# Laravel - Display Active and Inactive on the same page

Tags: laravel

I have a table with these fields: `name` and `plan_status`.

The `plan_status` can be `0` or `1`. `1` is active, `0` is inactive. I want to display `|name|active|inactive|`.

I am only able to run a query that displays either active and inactive ones.

Model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'plan_status'
];
```

Controller:

```
$actives = DB::table('users')
    ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as active'))
    ->where('plan_status', 1)
```

I want the query to display both names, active and inactive: `|name|active|inactive|`.

Comment: You don't need the where clause if you want them all. If a plan is either active or inactive, it means you want all.

Comment: I don't get it. Do you want to display all items in a table with both columns `active` and `inactive`, or just want to count items in function of their `plan_status`?

Comment: You can simply make a new array after the return and do
$actives['inactive'] = $actives['active'] ? false : true;

Comment: There will be 3 columns to be displayed. column one is name. Then, where plan_status is 1 column two will be displayed as active and where plan_status is 0 column two will be displayed as inactive. I dont want to put both active and inactive on plan status on the same column. I want to split them. Thanks

Comment: First: "*where plan_status is 1 __column two__ will be displayed as active and where plan_status is 0 __column two__ will be displayed as inactive*", then: "* I __dont want__ to put both active and inactive on plan status on __the same column__.*". - Still not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the query which will provide you exact result which you want

```
$actives = DB::table('users')
                     ->selectRaw('
                            name,  
                            IF((plan_status = 1), "Yes", "No") as active, 
                            IF((plan_status = 0), "Yes", "No") as inactive,
                            IF((plan_status = 2), "Yes", "No") as undefined
                     ')
                     ->get()
```

Try this and check. I think this will solve your problem.

**Edited**

To get count of status wise

```
$actives = DB::table('users')
                         ->selectRaw('
                                name,  
                                IF((plan_status = 1), COUNT(*), "0") as active, 
                                IF((plan_status = 0), COUNT(*), "0") as inactive,
                                IF((plan_status = 2), COUNT(*), "0") as undefined
                         ')
                         ->groupBy('plan_status')
                         ->get()
```

like this

[image]

Try both the solutions.

Comment: Am sorry, plan_status has 2 for undefined.: Active, inactive, undefined

Comment: you mean you have three types of values in `plan_status` => 0, 1, null. right?

Comment: and you want to count null values in 0 plan_status. right?

Comment: No, I have plan_status=> 0,1,2.   0 is inactive, 1 is active, 2 is undefined. It will count each as a column to be displayed on the same table

Comment: How about if I want to remove the attribute **name**, and have only one  row and two coloumns: active | inactive

Comment: just remove `name` from `selectRaw` condition.

Answer (score 0):

try this one using group by

```
 DB::table('users')
        ->select('name',
             DB::raw('IF((plan_status = 1), count(*), 0) as active'),
             DB::raw('IF((plan_status = 0), count(*), 0) as inactive'),
         )->groupBy('plan_status')->get()
```

Comment: I need to count each plan_status